# a question on measure theory for lebesgue measurable set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

let An be a sequence of subset of $R^k$. For every n there exist a lebesgue measurable set $En$ such that $An ⊆En$ with $Ei∩Ej=Ø$ for $i≠j$. we want to prove that $λ*(∪An)=Σλ*(An)$
where $λ*$ is the lebesgue outer measure
my approach is : if for every A we can find B with $A ⊆B$ where B is lebesgue measurable and also
$λ(B)<λ(A)+ε/2^n$  then we  done since  we would have $λ(UAn)<λ(UΒn)=Σλ(Bn)<Σλ(An)+ε$
so my question is : Does such B exist? And how do i prove it ?

Comment: Are those $A_{n}$ mesurable sets?

Comment: You should know by now that you should use MathJax for formulas. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this user should know by now to use MathJax.

Comment: @GabrielPalau we dont know if An are mesurable , if there where since Ei∩Ej=Ø for i≠j. we would have the same for An, so λ*(∪An)=Σλ*(An)  would be true

Comment: To render indices, write for example `A_n` or `A_{n}`. The braces are needed if the index consists of more than one symbol: `A_{m+n}` gives $A_{m+n}$ while `A_m+n` gives $A_m+n$.

Comment: Hint: By definition of measurability, 
$$\mu^*(A_1 \cup A_2) = \mu^*((A_1 \cup A_2) \cap E_1) + \mu^*((A_1 \cup A_2) \setminus E_1) = \mu^*(A_1) + \mu^*(A_2).$$ Extend this to finite sums, and then to the countable sum.